# Poker : Counting three of a kind and only that.

Tags: combinatorics

I consider a deck of $52$ cards, and a hand consists of $7$ cards.

> There is a classical question : counting three of a kind, there is 
>     $$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{3} \binom{12}{4} \left( \binom{4}{1} \right)^4$$

ways to count them, but yesterday my friend ( a poker player) said that I considered the possibility to have a sequence of four cards:  I choose the suits $\binom{4}{3}$, let's say I have *As-As-As* now it remains $5$ cards. But when I select four ranks from the remaining twelve ranks, we can have: **AS AS AS K Q J Ten** which give us a sequence of four cards and then it's better than the three of a kind.

So my question is :

> How can delete the possibility to have a sequence of four cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in poker you need a sequence of five cards to make a straight, which is the hand you are worrying about beating three of a kind.  Your example has a straight, but AAA3456 has a sequence of four and does not have a straight.  You also have to worry about the possibility of a full house, but your way of counting avoids that.

To remove the hands with both a straight and three of a kind, you just need to count them.  I would count the straights that have the two extra cards matching one of the cards in the straight.  If we assume you allow A2345 as a straight (some do not), there are $10$ highest ranks of the straight, $5$ ways to pick the card of the straight that has the three of a kind, and $4^5$ ways to choose the suits (the suit of the unmatched cards and the missing suit of the triplet) for a total of $10 \cdot 5 \cdot 4^5$ hands that must be deleted.

Comment: in my head I was thinking on how can I count three of a kind without straight, but not to delete them after that, thanks!